# CSS Horizontal Menu

Tags: html, css, menu, width

I am having an issue with this horizontal menu bar. It is suppose to fit the window (width wise) but continues a little bit further than it should. It is also suppose to be top:0;left:0;

Everything I do either one of two things works. Either I align it the top left but the width is too large, or it's not aligned and the width does fit.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Website Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    body{
    }

    .bg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -5000;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        height:33px;
        font-size:.6em;
        background: #76B3F1 url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat-x top left;
        font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        border:1px solid #000;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }

    #cssmenu li {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #cssmenu li a {
        float:left;
        color:#A79787;
        text-decoration:none;
        height:24px;
        padding:9px 15px 0;
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    #cssmenu li a:hover,.current {
        color:#fff;
        background: #A3BAE6 url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat-x top left;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #cssmenu .current a {
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:700;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
           <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="background">
        <img src="background/001.JPG" class="bg"/>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Probably the border. try using `left:0;right:0;` instead of `width:100%`

Comment: [Let me put that in a jsfiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkvy9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the CSS3 property `box-sizing` as Rockafella suggested, you can try [this edit of your CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkvy9/4/).

I got rid of your `position: absolute`, added `1px` padding to the `<div>` container, and added `-1px` margin to the `<ul>`. This way, the `width: 100%` on the `<ul>` makes the width of the *content box* not include the 1px border you specified.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `box-sizing: border-box;` css property.

This tells the menu to take the border into account when calculating '100%'

Comment: Note that this isn't supported in old IE (IE7 or earlier), and needs a vendor prefix in firefox and old versions of chrome/safari. http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was causing the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far seem cumbersome, so to re-post my comment as an answer:

Simply change the `width:100%` to `left:0;right:0` in the `ul` style. This is supported in everything better than IE6. If you need to support IE6, use its `expression` syntax:

```
width:expression((this.parentNode.offsetWidth-2)+'px')
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow-x: hidden` to your `body`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a border, how about using an inset box-shadow? You'd need to get your prefix on, and it wouldn't work in older IE. As far as I'm concerned, the industry has turned the corner on older IE and understands that it's not worth the trouble giving it all the shadows and rounded corners.

```
box-shadow:inset 0 0 1px 0 #000;
```

Comment: `box-shadow: 1px 1px #000 inset, -1px -1px #000 inset;`

Comment: @MattCoughlin actually `box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #000` is better; there's a little-known 4th value you can specify in `box-shadow` which tells it to grow/shrink.

Comment: @Dave: Good call! Hadn't thought to try the 4th value. Much better that way!